# Android NonSdkApiUsedViolation

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-console

I have just uploaded the app in beta on play store and after reviewed app got following warnings.

Note: Target version-28

[image]

[image]

[image]

Expanded All items and found "at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java)" in all issues.

Comment: expand the warnings and check what they say